# Can CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2 run without .Net 4.0?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Could you please tell me what are the requirements for running SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (64-bit)?

-Does .NET 4.0 must be required?

-Does .NET 3.5 or 3.5 SP1 support this program?

-Is there any error occurs when running SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (64-bit) on a machine only has .NET 2.0, 3.5 or 3.5 SP1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal 13 is the version for VS2010 and it requires .NET Framework 4. The runtime is available as a msi and it will not check for prerequisites (this will be done by setup.exe). When you deploy your project, add .NET Framework 4 as a prerequisites and the generated setup.exe will install it if necessary